# Parsing and Displaying JSON Data in Web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, api

Ive been trying to parse and display the json data returned by
a REST API without success.

Tested locally, the API is of form:

```
http://localhost/apiurl/get-data.php
```

And it returns data in form:

```
[{"title":"Title One","message":"Message One"},{"title":"title two","message":"message two"},....]
```

Each item consist of two elements ; title and message as shown above.

I want to loop through all returned items and display the result in a div like this

```
<p>Title One</p>
<p>Message One</p>
```

Etc.

Ive tried something like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
var url="http://localhost/apiurl/get-data.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
$.each(data,function(i,dat){
$("#resultid").append(
'<p>Title : <em>'+dat.title+'</em>'+
'<p>Message : <em>'+dat.message+'</em></p>'+
'<hr>'
);
});
});
});
</script>
```

but it didn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JS console? Also, try logging the `json` variable after you get it. Does it contain the data you want?

Comment: Change $.getJSON(url,function(json) to $.getJSON(url,function(data)

Comment: @Dipen Shah This works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it started working after changing the value to `json instead of data` 
check this out 
[image]

Comment: Passing variable and accessing variable names should be same!!

Comment: Yes. It works, even with json. But I had to remove all html tags first from the url file...<html>, <head>, <body>, seems that was the cause the cause of the problem. Thanks